# [Error: Error: Failed to fetch patients: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mariadb, next.js13

I'm trying to query mysql database in nodejs by using a searchString grabbed from the user input at the frontend of my application. But i cannot do so and am failing to find a solution to the problem.

My code;

```
export async function fetchAllPatients({
  searchString = "",
  pageNumber = 1,
  pageSize = 20,
  sortBy = "desc"
}: {
  searchString?: string;
  pageNumber?: number;
  pageSize?: number;
  sortBy?: SortOrder;
}): Promise<{
  patients: any[];
  isNext: boolean;
}> {
  let db: Connection | null = null;

  try {
    // connect to the database
    db = connectToDatabase();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Calculate the number of patients to skip based on the page number
      const skipAmount = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;

      // Building an SQL query
      let sql = 'SELECT id, firstName, lastName, sex, age, residence, enrollmentDate FROM patients';

      // Constructing the WHERE clause for searching
      if (searchString.trim() !== '') {
        sql += ` WHERE CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) LIKE ?`;
      }

      // Adding ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses for pagination and sorting
      sql += ` ORDER BY enrollmentDate ${sortBy.toUpperCase()} LIMIT ?, ?`;

      // Executing the SQL query
      const searchParam = searchString.trim() !== '' ? `%${searchString}%` : ''; // Handle empty searchString
      db?.query(sql, [searchParam, skipAmount, pageSize], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(`Error fetching patients: ${error.message}`);
          reject(`Failed to fetch patients: ${error.message}`);
        } else {
          // map the results to the desired format
          const patients = results.map((patient: any) => ({
            id: patient.id,
            fullName: `${patient.firstName} ${patient.lastName}`,
            sex: patient.sex,
            age: patient.age,
            residence: patient.residence,
            enrollmentDate: formatDate(patient.enrollmentDate),
          }));
```

My error on the terminal;

Failed to fetch patients: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''', 0' at line 1
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: some where you add two % to an empty search string, so you must check the code where you do this. this osn't that bad but searchString.trim() will so never be emtpy, it will have at least a %% in it

Comment: ok i have tried to add this line of code "const searchParam = searchString.trim() !== '' ? `%${searchString}%` : ''; " before executing the query in order to handle the empty searchString but still i get an error that looks like this   "[Error: Error: Failed to fetch patients: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''', 0' at line 1] {      
  digest: '193452068'
}"

Comment: please show your new code

Comment: Show us the constructed query.  Whatever comes before `%%` is critical to answering the question.

Comment: this is some of my new code.  "if (searchString.trim() !== '') {
          sql += ' WHERE CONCAT(firstName, " ", lastName) LIKE ?';
        }
  
        // Adding ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses for pagination and sorting
        sql += ` ORDER BY enrollmentDate ${sortBy.toUpperCase()} LIMIT ?, ?`;
  
        // Executing the SQL query
        const searchParam = searchString.trim() !== '' ? `%${searchString}%` : ''; // Handle empty searchString
        db?.query(sql, [searchParam, skipAmount, pageSize], (error, results) => {"

Comment: please don't try to show your code or in comments, edit your question instead

Comment: yap actually have just edited it now to bring out the concept more clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are unconditionally including the search string

```
[`%${searchString}%`, skipAmount, pageSize]
```

even when the WHERE clause is not added because the search string is ''.

This results in sql:

```
SELECT id, firstName, lastName, sex, age, residence, enrollmentDate FROM patients
ORDER BY enrollmentDate ${sortBy.toUpperCase()} LIMIT ?, ?
```

so the search string is used for the first `?`, producing an error on:

```
LIMIT '%%',0
```

Do something like:

```
db?.query(sql, ((searchString.trim() !== '') ? [`%${searchString}%`, skipAmount, pageSize] : [skipAmount, pageSize])...
```

Comment: thank you have tried that and it looks like the error is gone

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it like this

```
let sql = 'SELECT id, firstName, lastName, sex, age, residence, enrollmentDate FROM patients';

// Constructing the WHERE clause for searching
if (searchString.trim() !== '') {
  sql += ' WHERE CONCAT(firstName, " ", lastName) LIKE ?';
}

// Adding ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses for pagination and sorting
sql += ' ORDER BY enrollmentDate ' + sortBy.toUpperCase() + ' LIMIT ?, ?';
```

Comment: read my comment and the error message